# Akka Ensure Poison Pill is Consumed

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I would like to get a future that completes when an Akka actor has handled the PoisonPill.

I have tried:

someRef ? PoisonPill

but this never completes.  I think you can only use '!' and not '?'.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to monitor the life-cycle of some child actor, you can simply `watch` that actor and handle the `Terminated` message accordingly to your logic. For example:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

  import context._ // to avoid writing context everywhere

  val child = actorOf(Props(new ChildActor)) // ChildActor is the type of the actor you are monitoring, the child
  watch(child) // subscribe to the Terminated message of the child

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "kill" ⇒ child ! PoisonPill // kill the child. You could also use context.stop(child)
    case Terminated(`child`) ⇒ println("child died") // handle the termination of the child. Use back-ticks to make child a stable identifier
    case _ ⇒ println("meh") // who cares
  }
}
```

Now, if you want an explicit `Future`, the first thing that pops in my mind is passing a `Promise` to the actor you want to watch, and override `postStop` to complete the promise. It would look like this:

```
class MyActor(p: Promise[Unit]) extends Actor { // receive the Promise to complete

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ ⇒ println("meh") // who cares
  }

  override def postStop(): Unit = { // after stopped
    p.tryComplete(Success(())) // complete the promise
  }
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem("test")
    val p = Promise[Unit]()
    val f = p.future // get the future from the promise
    val a = system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor(p))) // send the promise to the actor you want to watch

    f onSuccess { // register a callback when the future completes
      case _ ⇒ println("actor died")
    }

    a ! "foo"
    a ! PoisonPill
  }
}
```

Hope it helped. Cheers!